# Editable Combobox selected item not shown

Tags: wpf

I have 3 different categories (fruit, vegetable, and household) collection shown as a combobox. I am trying to make this editable, when the user enters an item, it should be selected if available in collection else added to the collection. Selected item should be shown in combobox and item.name should be shown in textblock next to combo box.

Also, I have a load button with default values for this combobox, these are not loading.

Can anyone help here, please?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.Views.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{DynamicResource myVMViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:myVM x:Key="myVMViewModel"></local:myVM>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Window 2" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding AttributeCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttrName}" MinWidth="125" Margin="5"/>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" 
                              MinWidth="125" 
                              Margin="5"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttr,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              Text="{Binding NewItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedAttr.Name}" MinWidth="125" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="5">
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadData}" Content="LoadData" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="125"></Button>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
</Window>

namespace WpfApp5.Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class myVM : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand LoadData { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Attribute> attributeCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Attribute> AttributeCollection
    {
        get { return attributeCollection; }
        set { SetProperty(ref attributeCollection, value); }
    }

    Attribute obj;
    Attribute obj2;
    Attribute obj3;

    public myVM() {

        LoadData = new DelegateCommand(LoadDataClick, CanLoadDataClick);

        AttributeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Attribute>();

        obj = new Attribute();
        obj.AttrName = "Fruits";
        obj.ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<itemData>();
        obj.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 100, Name = "Apple" });
        obj.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 101, Name = "Banana" });
        obj.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 102, Name = "Mango" });
        obj.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 103, Name = "Orange" });

        obj2 = new Attribute();
        obj2.AttrName = "Vegitable";
        obj2.ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<itemData>();
        obj2.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 200, Name = "Potato" });
        obj2.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 201, Name = "Tomato" });
        obj2.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 202, Name = "Onion" });
        obj2.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 203, Name = "Carrot" });


        obj3 = new Attribute();
        obj3.AttrName = "Household";
        obj3.ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<itemData>();
        obj3.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 300, Name = "Towel" });
        obj3.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 301, Name = "Mop" });
        obj3.ItemsCollection.Add(new itemData() { ID = 302, Name = "Mat" });


        AttributeCollection.Add(obj);
        AttributeCollection.Add(obj2);
        AttributeCollection.Add(obj3);

    }

    private bool CanLoadDataClick()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void LoadDataClick()
    {
        itemData fruitItem = new itemData{ ID = 102, Name = "Mango" };
        itemData vegItem = new itemData { ID = 200, Name = "Potato" };
        itemData householdItem = new itemData { ID = 300, Name = "Towel" };

        obj.SelectedAttr = fruitItem;
        obj2.SelectedAttr = vegItem;
        obj3.SelectedAttr = householdItem;


    }
}

public class Attribute : BindableBase
{
    private string attrName;
    public string AttrName
    {
        get { return attrName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref attrName, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<itemData> itemsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<itemData> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return itemsCollection; }
        set { SetProperty(ref itemsCollection, value); }
    }

    private object selectedAttr;
    public object SelectedAttr
    {
        get { return selectedAttr; }
        set { SetProperty(ref selectedAttr, value); }
    }

    private string newItem;
    public string NewItem
    {
        get { return newItem; }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedAttr != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                itemData newValue = new itemData() { ID = 100, Name = value };
                ItemsCollection.Add(newValue);
                SelectedAttr = newValue;
            }

            SetProperty(ref newItem, value);
        }
    }



}

public class itemData : BindableBase
{
    private int id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref id, value); }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure this is the exact answer you're looking for, but I can not comment below your question due to my site rep, new user)

I can see your binding your ComboxBox to the ItemsCollection and displaying the Name member of these.

Does this help if you load the item source of the ComboBox to be your ItemsCollection? Eg.

```
YourComboBoxNameHere.ItemsSource = ItemsCollection;
```

Comment: Code i have works, but when i select combobox value it doesnt show. Also values are not loading when load button clicked